# Windows forms c# area chart adding a point that wasn't specified

Tags: c#, winforms

so this is a really weird bug. I have an array of points, name pointsArr, and I add all the points to an area series in a regular chart as follows:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < pointsArr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            chart1.Series["תחום הפתרונות האפשריים"].Points.AddXY(pointsArr[i, 0], pointsArr[i, 1]);
            Console.WriteLine($"{ pointsArr[i, 0]},{pointsArr[i, 1] }");
        }
        chart1.Series["תחום הפתרונות האפשריים"].Points.AddXY(pointsArr[0, 0], pointsArr[0, 1]);//The first point in the array, AKA 0,6. as far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with the problem.
```

In the console, the log is:

0,6

0,0

6,6

but, in the area chart at the result for no reason it adds another point at (6,0)
[image]

P.S I have another point series that you can see in the picture and that series works fine and is not related to the problem.

EDIT 1:

Ok so here is the graph without the last line:

```
chart1.Series["תחום הפתרונות האפשריים"].Points.AddXY(pointsArr[0, 0], pointsArr[0, 1]);
```

[image: new graph]

EDIT 2:

progress update:
so this is just getting weirder. if I change the order of the points in the pointsArr array, the outcome of the area series is different. If I do it in the current order, the result is the second image. If I put the points in any other order it shows the rectangle, and all this without the 4th line

```
chart1.Series["תחום הפתרונות האפשריים"].Points.AddXY(pointsArr[0, 0], pointsArr[0, 1]);
```

Comment: Where can we see a point at (6,0) ? Can you see it in the Points collection? - What is the ChartTyxpe: Area or StackedArea100 ?

Comment: It is regular area. I can see the point in the drawing. It is a rectangle instead of a triangle, and one of the points is 6,0 which I didn't specify.

Comment: So it is in the Points collection, right? At which index?? You will have to use the debugger to observe when it is added.. You may also want to do a project search for AddXY in the code (including the designer.cs file).. It certainly is not added by itself!

Comment: The point 6,0 is not in the point collection and I don't want it to be. So weird!

Comment: I will get home from work in an hour and show you what happens after I remove that line. Basically it draws a triangle with the points  (6,0) (6,6) (0,0) it still shoudn't draw that triangle.